Alternate way of proving a relation is not a transitive relation
Here's the question:

Let $R$ be a relation on the set of real numbers defined by aRb $\iff ab > -1$. Is $R$ an equivalence relations?

I was able to prove that R is symmetric and reflexive.
But R is not transitive and I proved it by taking an example.
$\text{Let (a,b) and (b,c) be (-10,0) and (0,10) }$
$\text{because}-10\cdot0 > -1 \text{ and } 0\cdot10 >-1 \implies (-10,0),(0,10)\in R $
$ \text{For R to be transitive (a,c) i.e (-10,10) should belong to R but } -10\cdot10  <-1\implies(-10,10) \notin R$
$\text{So R is not transitive because it did not satisfy the condition of transitivity for (-10,0) and (0,10) which are real numbers}$
Is there a better way to prove that R is not transitive? The solution also used an example to prove that R is not transitive.

It's the best way. To prove an existential statement (which is the negation of the universal statement of transitivity), nothing beats actually producing an explicit example. Certainly much better than a long argument that ends with "and there is no reason why this would have to be the case"...
